# How do I include a menu item into the pre-existing menu from a Superclass Activity?

Tags: android, menu

I have an custom Activity that I'm going to extend to introduce some default functionality that I need across a multitude of applications I'm building.

My goal is to add a couple of menu items from the Superclass so that the subclass Activities don't have to every think about them. They can have their own menu behavior and the Superclass will just inject its default menu items into the overal menu.

I'm looking at the docs here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#intents and I get the feeling that I'm required to know the ID of the menu group into which I'm hoping to add these items, but my goal is for the Superclass to have no express knowledge of the details of the other menu items or their wrapper and just to find whatever the existing menu layout exists and add stuff to it.

Is this possible, or do I have to make sure that all my menu layouts are normalized across all apps and prepare an item for the superclass to inject its menu items into?

Comment: I don't think you'd need anything other than calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);` before inflating the menu in your subclass. Also make sure you call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);` if the menu item doesn't match any known item for that subclass.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the question but if the subclass inflates its menu and then calls `super.onOptionsMenuCreate(Menu menu)`, then the superclass can then use the various `menu.add...` methods in order to add new menu items.

Comment: @Squonk, just to be clear subclass creates its menu. Superclass then adds a couple of items to it.  I don't want the two stepping on each other. I want the subclass to inflate the menu and the Superclass to add items to it. Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel : If you `@Override` the `onCreateOptionsMenu(...)` method, remember it will be called instead of the superclass version of that method. If you then call the `super` method and pass in the `Menu` that the subclass has created then the superclass can simply add to it. the add methods don't delete what is already there. Also as ebarrenchea mentioned, call `super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem)` from the subclass if it doesn't recognise the item as one of its own.

Comment: ah! very nice... I'll with that solution

Comment: works nicely. If you'd like the green checkmark please answer the question as an answer.